# ViewBox font not legible to minimum resolution

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the `ViewBox` for display a list of labels in horizontal orientation and keep the legibilitym, the problem's that when I reduce the window to a minimum resolution that I set to: `800` I get this result:

[image]

how you can see the I can't read the contents. This situation only happen when the window is to minimum resolution, when is on max resolution the `ViewBox` working pretty good:

[image]

I don't know if I did something wrong. I never used the `ViewBox`, this is my code:

```
<Viewbox TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="0, 1, 0, 0">
            <Label Content="Foo" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventLeague}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0,-10, 0, 0">
            <Label Content="Date" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0,-10, 0, 0">
            <Label Content="Week" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventGameWeek}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         </Grid>
         <Grid Margin="0,-10, 0, 0">
             <Label Content="Home" FontWeight="Bold"/>
             <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventStart}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         </Grid>
         <Grid Margin="0,-10, 0, 0">
             <Label Content="Away" FontWeight="Bold"/>
             <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventStadium}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         </Grid>
     </StackPanel>  
  </Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Grids have no rows or column this means that everything goes into grid cell 0,0 on top of each other

try this

```
<Viewbox TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" MinHeight="500"  MinWidth="500" >
        <UniformGrid Columns="2">
            <Label Content="Foo" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventLeague}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Content="Date" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Content="Week" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventGameWeek}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Content="Home" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventStart}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Content="Away" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path = EventStadium}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         </UniformGrid >
  </Viewbox>
```

Edit:

as you have clarified that the size is your problem not the unreadability of the controls

then the way a viewbox works is that is performs an image stretch on what ever is inside it to make it fit inside it,

so if the ViewBox is 100 wide but the items inside are 500 width then they are shrunk to 1/5 of their original size so as to fit

as you have `Stretch="Uniform"` then it will maintain the aspect ratio while shrinking and growing, if the size of the control is too small then set the `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` values of the  Viewbox to control the minimum size

Comment: this only optimize the code removing the multiple grid, but the resolution problem remain..

Comment: its removing the overlapping controls which is whats causing the overlapping text in the boxes which is what makes the screen shot unreadable to me

Comment: you're right but this is another bug. Now is fixed, but still the main problem of the question remain. When the window resolution is to minimum I get no legibility of the text, there is something that I can use for prevent text to go out of legibility? Thanks.